# How to work with jQuery no-conflict mode and multiple script locations

Tags: scope, closures, jquery

What a crappy title. Maybe someone can edit it for me. Here's the scoop:

I need to work in jQuery no-conflict mode, but I'd still like to take advantage of the $ shortcut, so all of my functions etc are defined within the typical closure of `(function($){ ... })(jQuery);`

All this is defined in an external source.js file that is included at the top of my HTML web page.

A little later on, I need to add some inline `<script>` that uses one of the utility functions I defined within the closure. Obviously I've namespaced myself into a box and can't access that function.

What's the right pattern to use here?

Comment: Inline scripts are perfectly fine for initializing your javascript. It helps testability, and it is needed when the javascript needs data injected by the server.

Comment: I actually agree with kingjiv, generally. In this particular case, it really improves the readability and maintainability of the code for other developers (WordPress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control how much and what you expose in the global namespace, it is custom to expose what you need through one global object, usually in all capital letters.

```
FOO.module1.init();
FOO.module2.init();
```

You would do this by making sure FOO exists, and if it doesn't: create it.

```
var FOO = this.FOO || {};
```

The same for your module namespaces:

```
FOO.module1 = FOO.module1 || {};
```

and then inside of the anonymous function, expose what you want.

## Complete example

**module1.js:**

```
var FOO = this.FOO || {};
FOO.module1 = FOO.module1 || {};

(function ($) {
    var my, local, data;

    function init() {
        // use my, local and data here.
    }

    FOO.module1.init = init;
}(jQuery));
```

**module2.js:**

```
var FOO = this.FOO || {};
FOO.module2 = FOO.module2 || {};

(function ($) {
    var some, other, data;

    function init() {
        // use some, other and data here.
    }

    FOO.module2.init = init;
}(jQuery));
```

**controller.js:**

```
FOO.module1.init();
FOO.module2.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

Magnar's answer is the way to go for anything complex.  But just for the sake of completeness, for something very simple you can just make it global like this:

```
$.noConflict();

(function($){
    window.doSomething = function(){
        $("body").css("background-color","red");
    }        
})(jQuery);


doSomething();
```

by adding the function to `window` it becomes global.

http://jsfiddle.net/cxTYV/

Comment: +1 Thanks King, this is great too for a quickie. I could only accept one answer so I went with the one that seemed more "formal". I never thought of attaching a custom property to the window object. Makes sense.