# programatically switching between jquery library and 3rd party library

Tags: jquery

We are using a 3rd party java script library for functionalities like drag-drop, calender etc. Now are planning to move to jQuery for these controls & effects.

The 3rd party uses $(DOMElement) like jQuery to add the extension methods to the control(say converting a textbox to calender).
jQuery also uses the same syntax.

We are not completely replacing the 3rd party library with jQuery. So in some place $(element) should refer to the 3rd party library, while in some places in the same page, it should refer to jQuery.

Is there a way to programatically specify which which library the $(element) should refer.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use jQuery noConflict() but it would be less work to just assign jQuery to something else

So use jQuery('.item') rather than $('.item')

If ou want to keep things short:

```
var x = {};
x.query = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

and then go on your merry way

```
x('.item')
```

Comment: Jus need a clarification, After this, x.query = jQuery.noConflict(true); x refers to the jQuery or the other API?

Comment: In this example, x refers to jQuery. You could do it the other way around by saying var x = {}; x = $; ----- $ refering to the old library

Comment: I used the following solution
var x = $;
$.noConflict();
//Code using $ as 3rd part API reference.
$ = x;
//Code using $ as jquery reference.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`jQuery.noConflict();`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) like this.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
    });
})(jQuery);
```

`$` is just an alias for `jQuery` object. So, alternatively, you can do this.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
jQuery("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. Could you please tell me the scope of the noConflict(). If am doing it in one of the js file, then will the other js files also see this, noConflict()?

Comment: just remember to serve it before any other jQuery code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430769/how-to-work-with-jquery-no-conflict-mode-and-multiple-script-locations